# stacked barplot with total and edited axis limit - python

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

I'm trying to do a stacked barplot, but it seems to be pretty tricky with `seaborn`. I have this data:

```
x = pd.DataFrame({"Groups" : np.random.choice(["Group1", "Group2", "Group3"], 100),
                 "Sex" : np.random.choice(["Masculine", "Femenine"], 100)})
x = x.groupby(["Groups", "Sex"]).size().reset_index(name="count")
x["percent (%)"] = round(x.groupby("Groups").transform(lambda x: x/sum(x))*100,1)
x
```

[image]

And I have this plot:

```
sns.barplot(x="Groups", y="percent (%)", hue="Sex", data=x);
```

[image]

However, I'm  looking that each group has a stacked bar, the y-axis from 0 to 1, and a "group4" with a total. When I try to plot the limits like [here](https://python-graph-gallery.com/44-control-axis-limits-of-plot-seaborn/) it gives me an error as this seaborn graph doesn't allow it, and every stacked barplot from seaborn I have found have a column per each group with the values of each group in his respective column and I have all the groups in one column. Any ideas?

I'm looking for a simple solution (with or without seaborn) without changuing the structure of the data (except for adding the "total group", but I don't know if it's easier to add the total to the data, or computing the total inside the graph).

Comment: The creator of seaborn is known for being quite opinionated. [Here](https://github.com/mwaskom/seaborn/issues/1485#issuecomment-403049638) is what he thinks about stacked bar charts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure what `group4` would look like, here's a stacked bar graph:

```
x = pd.DataFrame({"Groups" : np.random.choice(["Group1", "Group2", "Group3"], 100),
                 "Sex" : np.random.choice(["Masculine", "Femenine"], 100)})

xf = x.groupby(["Groups"])['Sex'].value_counts().unstack('Groups')
xf['Total'] = xf.sum(1)
xf.div(xf.sum()).T.plot.bar(stacked=True)
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: This almost solves my question, but the X-axis should have the Groups (when I do this it works, but the percentages are always 50%, why do you normalize?). The "total group" is just another bar, with is the sum of all the counts of the other three groups.

Comment: Why? For example, group1 have 2 men (20%) and 8 women (80%), and group2 have 5 men (50%) and 5 women (50%), giving a total of 7 man (35%) and 13 woman (65%) for the "total group". It fits in the scale 0-1.

Comment: yup !. I need the X-axis to be the groups, and the % of the bars representing the males and females (like in the plot I gave in the question, but stacked)

Comment: It works!. But all the stacked bars gave me 50% each when in the dataframe doesn't have 50%. This is the full code I used to check it: `x = pd.DataFrame({"Groups" : np.random.choice(["Group1", "Group2", "Group3"], 1000),
                 "Sex" : np.random.choice(["Masculine", "Femenine"], 1000)})
x = x.groupby(["Groups", "Sex"]).size().reset_index(name="count")
x["percent (%)"] = round(x.groupby("Groups").transform(lambda x: x/sum(x))*100,3)
display(x)
xf = x.groupby(["Groups"])['Sex'].value_counts().unstack('Groups')
xf['Total'] = xf.sum(1)
xf.div(xf.sum()).T.plot.bar(stacked=True);`

Comment: No, my code applies to the original `x`. See updated.

Comment: Got it!, but you are changuing the structure of the data to plot. If you print your 'xf' before plotting it, the structure it's different from the image of the data structure I gave in the question. I asked to not change the data sctructure because that's the table I have already, so I changed it in order for your code to work (and it does :D). But for the question quality, please specify you changed the structure of the data.